# JPA JoinColumns behaviour

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
class Employee {

   @EmbeddedId
   private EmployeeId id; // composite key with two fileds companyId and employeeNumber

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<Phone> phoneList;
}

class Phone {

  @EmbeddedId
  private PhoneId phoneId; // composite key with three fileds companyId , employeeNumber and phoneNumber

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID", referencedColumnName = "COMPANY_ID", insertable = false, 
        updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER_NEW", referencedColumnName = "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER", 
        insertable = false, updatable = false)})
  private Employee employee;

}
```

In above example,  Employee table gets generated with column employeeId, employeeNumber. And Phone table gets generated with  employeeId, employeeNumber, phoneNumber, employee_nuber_new.

When I am creating employee object and phone object, at the end employeeId and employeeNumber values in Phone table gets populated from Employee object ( as part of FK ) but employee_number_new column still have "null" value.  I want to updated employee_number_new column with employeeNumber from Employee table.

Tried lot of ways including JoinFormula and all but no success.  Can anybody throw some light on this ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting a `null` value in the Phone table because you are using `insertable = false` in your `JoinColumn` definition. If you could set this to `true` then your problem would be solved.

Hibernate doesn't support the mixing of insertable and non-insertable columns. So you have to make `companyId` insertable too. But that leads to the possibility of your primary key being changed in the `Phone` table which you don't want.

So, we are left with two options, if the `EMPLOYEE_NUMBER` is the same in both tables don't create the new column `EMPLOYEE_NUMBER_NEW` column and use `EMPLOYEE_NUMBER`.

But if `EMPLOYEE_NUMBER` is not the same in both tables then and you need to save the employee number from employee object, create another insertable column it can be `COMPANY_ID_EMP` and make updateable false. That way when you save a phone object both `EMPLOYEE_NUMBER_NEW` and `COMPANY_ID_EMP` will be saved. But in practice `COMPANY_ID_EMP` and `COMPANY_ID` will be the same value.

The following code worked for me

```java
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "companyIdEmp", referencedColumnName = "companyId",  updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "employeeNumberNew", referencedColumnName = "employeeNumber", updatable = false)})
    private Employee employee;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for response. We kind of tried this solution earlier but because of new column creation we didn't take that. Any idea, if we can resolve this using joinformula's.